# Is there a delay in count data appearing the Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm creating a series of web pages, each of which will contain a [Facebook "Like" button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), as well as display a count of how many people have liked the page.

As a test, I set up a simple page containing "Like" buttons for two discreet URLs (differentiated by the value of the `bracket` query parameter; either `101` or `201`). The test page also contains some code that uses the Facebook JavaScript SDK and FQL queries to load some of the available data for the two URLs:

- http://massrelevance_uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/turner-sports/si-social-buzz/test3.html

The response from the Facebook API can be seen in the browser console after loading the test page:

- https://skitch.com/troywarr/ghrfk/test-3
- https://skitch.com/troywarr/ghrgq/test-3

As you can see from the second screenshot, even though the "Like" button shows a count of `1` (as a result of me clicking it), the API response still shows a `like_count` of `0`.

Why is this? Is there a delay in updating the counts on Facebook's side, or have I implemented this incorrectly or made some false assumptions?

Thanks for any help! Please let me know if you need additional information or a better explanation.

Comment: I might have figured this out. I had a friend click the "Like" buttons too, and I immediately started to see a `like_count` of `1`. That suggests to me that *my* likes aren't being included in the total, hence why I was still seeing a `like_count` of `0` when I expected to see `1`. Would love to know why that is, if anyone is able to reply with an answer to clarify that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a caching issue.  Sometime to make things performant, caching is used.  The downside to the cache is that statistics aren't always kept up to date in an immediate manner.